# All combinations of a list in Dart

Tags: dart

I need the classic N choose K algorithm to generate all the possible combinations of a list or iterable in Dart. Is there any implementation out there?

Comment: Something like https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/trotter?

Comment: Sounds perfect! Why don't you post the answer?

Answer (score 7):

The package [trotter](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/trotter) seems to do what you are looking for.

Comment: even through it looks cool, it doesn't have null safety as for Sept 1 2021

Comment: Any null-safety solution?

Comment: @goodniceweb checkout this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64302098/12695188

Answer (score 3):

There is now an unreleased null safety version of trotter. Add the following dependency to your pubspec.yaml:

`trotter: ^2.0.0-dev.1`

Then you can do something like [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/trotter/latest/trotter/Combinations-class.html):

```
var c = Combinations(3, characters('abcd'));
print('There are ${c.length} 3-combinations of the objects');
print('in ${c.items}.');
print('The first combination is ${c[0]}.');
```

You can make a Combinations object for a custom type as well:

```
var c = Combinations<MyType>(3, [obj1, obj2]);
```